# Windows server 2003, remote way to bypass windows firewall

Tags: windows-server, windows-firewall

I have a windows server 2003, I disabled the firewall with the remote desktop, enable it and I lost the access to my machine (and my sites). I was wondering if there is any backdoor to bypass firewall in situations like this, so if something goes wrong, I could fix it remotely.

In linux for example, there is ssh reverse tunneling which I have enable it and in similar situations I could connect anyway and fix any problem I created.

Comment: your question sounds like you trying to hack to someones server...otherwise you could call a web farm / hosting provider where server is located and ask crew in there to open then firewall for you using local access...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much your firewall is configured, but in case WMI is still working, you can open your local "Services" Management Console, connect to your remote computer, and stop the Windows Firewall Service.

If you install e.g. Teamviewer, you can also connect to because Teamviewer usually creates the firewall rules on it's own.

Comment: If he disabled Remote Desktop, what stops him from disabling Teamviewer in firewall rules?

Comment: Firewall is blocking everything, when I've done it I lost instantly connection to remote desktop and to my sites (I don't see my site either). I called my hosting and they will fix it but it has passed 4 hours and nothing yet, so I asked for a precaution.

Comment: @JohnDel, the only precaution you can have is to avoid dealing with firewall because you can block any application with which you can access your computer with. either it is Teamviewer, Logmein, Windows RDC or VNC.

Comment: @JohnDel, maybe ask your hosting for a hardware firewall in front of your server which is manageable without your server via web interface. Most hosting providers have this.